# Jupyter Notebook Kernel killed by async functions in Python

Tags: asynchronous, jupyter-notebook, kernel, python-asyncio

I'm using the libraries aiohttp and asyncio to make asynchronous/parallel API requests in Python. I'm very new to asynchronous programming so I have no idea what's going on and couldn't find it anywhere. It seems that Jupyter Notebook Kernel has some asynchronous tasks running in the background, so to avoid superposition of loops I used the nest_asyncio.apply() command before using the asynchronous functions. The problem is that the functions run, all the API requests are done, but after that the Kernel gets killed and I lose everything. I have already tried to change the async funtions and also how to call them, using run or get_event_loop with run_until_complete etc, but I didn't see any difference. Do you have any idea about what could be causing this issue, please?

```
nest_asyncio.apply()

async def fetch_url(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()
    
async def gather_fetched_urls(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: 
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_url(session, url)) for url in urls]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return results

URLs_list = []
responses = asyncio.run(gather_fetched_urls(URLs_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is that even if I create a new event loop, it may be not assigned to the right thread. I found this solution:

```
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    responses = loop.run_until_complete(gather_fetched_urls(URLs))
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the chosen answer if it solves your problem!